Using "send as" feature with gmail from custom domain not hosted by Google fails SPF and DKIM
I have my personal email address set as a "send as" option (i.e. an alias) on gmail, e.g. me@mydomain.com. I don't use Google for any services relating to mydomain.com, so I don't have an admin console or dashboard.
Email "sent as" my personal email address via the gmail web UI fails both SPF and DKIM, despite having v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com as a DNS TXT record for mydomain.com.
I see the following as an mxtoolbox report, specifically showing "Domain not found in SPF" and no DKIM signature found.

Is it possible to fix this with my personal domain name DNS entries? Or will this sort of email always fail DMARC/DKIM/SPF if Google is not hosting the domain name?
I've done some searching on this issue and everything I've found is advice when using Google admin/workspace. Here, the domain name and MX record are elsewhere, but gmail is configured to "send as" a user from this domain name.

SPF fails because Gmail sends emails via its servers (e.g. 209.85.208.46), but the SPF record for mydomain.com doesn’t align as the “From” domain (mydomain.com) and Return-Path domain (gmail.com) differ. Then DKIM fails because Gmail cannot sign emails for mydomain.com without access to the private DKIM key for the domain. Since both SPF and DKIM fail alignment, DMARC also fails.

So does this mean using Gmail "send as" by definition fails DMARC, unless you are just using "send as" for another Gmail address (or for a domain hosted at Google)? I thought including "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com" in my customer domain DNS TXT record would be sufficient to at least pass SPF, but apparently not. There is no way to pass SPF when the Return-Path domain and From domain don't match?

I should note that doing a similar "send as" via Protonmail works fine. I.e. Protonmail doesn't have my MX record, but is identified as a permissible sender in SPF and Protonmail's SMTP server is signing with DKIM. There is something different about how Gmail is sending as an alias versus how Protonmail does it.

These are the relevant headers for analysing the situation:
Return-Path: <my_address@gmail.com>
. . .
Authentication-Results: mail.protonmail.ch; dmarc=fail (p=none dis=none)
 header.from=example.com
Authentication-Results: mail.protonmail.ch; spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=gmail.com
Authentication-Results: mail.protonmail.ch; arc=none smtp.remote-ip=209.85.208.45
Authentication-Results: mail.protonmail.ch; dkim=none
. . .
From: My Name <my_address@example.com>

SPF is passing with the envelope sender domain google.com, which not aligned (see RFC 7489, 3.1) with the example.com used in the header From. As SPF is not aligned and DKIM signature not present at all, DMARC fails.
Possible solutions:

Use example.com as the envelope sender.
DKIM sign the message with a signature aligned with example.com.
Ideally, configure both DMARC+SPF & DMARC+DKIM alignments.

